# Format date with Jinja2 and python

Tags: python, datetime, jinja2

i need to format this date on the template because comes from the database on a dictionary.

I got this date displayed on my template:

```
1996-08-22
```

And i want to be like this:

```
22-08-1996
```

here is my code for it :

```
{{date['Fundação'] }}
```

I try to use with strftime but i got an error:

```
{{date['Fundação']|strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}
```

The error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'strftime'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the strftime code as well as the full text of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: Did you think strftime did exist? https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a python function that will handle the date.

You can consume it from your template.

Example:

```
def reverse_date(a_date):
  d = a_date.split('-')
  d.reverse()
  reverse_d = '-'.join(d)
  return reverse_d

template = Template('your template')
template.globals['reverse_date'] = reverse_date
# now you can use it in your template
{{ reverse_date(date['Fundação']) }}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tought was a standart function. But works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You can treat variables in a jinja2 template as Python ones. To change the date format use the `datetime` build-in method, not a filter:

```
{{date['Fundação'].strftime('%d-%m-%Y')}}
```